# LEFT JOIN нескольких таблиц выдаёт дубликаты

Tags: mysql, join, mariadb

Делаю билинговую систему к торговой интернет-площадке.
В таблицах `tbl_user` - пользователи, `tbl_billing_refill` - пополнения баланса, `tbl_billing` - покупки/продажи (если `id` пользователя совпадает с `buid` - это его покупка, если с `suid` - это его продажа)

Текущая задача - правильно посчитать баланс для конкретного пользователя с `id`=1.

**Упрощённые тестовые данные.**

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_user`
(
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` VARCHAR(32)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

INSERT INTO `tbl_user` (`name`) VALUES ('Вася'), ('Петя'), ('Боря');


CREATE TABLE `tbl_billing_refill`
(
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `uid` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `sum` DECIMAL(9,2) NOT NULL
)
ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

INSERT INTO `tbl_billing_refill` (`uid`, `sum`) VALUES
(1, 1), (1, 10), (1, 100), (1, 100), (2, 2), (2, 20), (3, 300);


CREATE TABLE `tbl_billing`
(
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `buid` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `suid` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `sum` DECIMAL(9,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
)
ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

INSERT INTO `tbl_billing` (`buid`,`suid`,`sum`) VALUES
(1, 3, 1), (1, 2, 10), (1, 2, 10), (1, 2, 100), (2, 1, 2), (2, 1, 2), (2, 1, 20), (3, 1, 300);
```

Запрос составил так:

1 Взял таблицу пользователей в качестве таблицы у которой гарантированно будут данные об `id` пользователя, что бы было к чему присоединять, а так мне данные из неё не нужны.

2 Мне нужен обязательно `OUTER` JOIN, так как любая из таблиц кроме `tbl_user`, в том числе и все сразу, могут не содержать данных об этом пользователе. Для этого же и использую `IFNULL`, чтобы `NULL` от таблицы с пустыми данными превратить в `0`.

3 `GROUP BY u.id` включил, так как я использую агрегатную функцию `SUM`, которая требует, ну или раньше до 10.0 требовала, обязательной группировки.
Запросы в MariaDB начиная с 10.0 уже выполняются и без неё, но ставлю по привычке.

Если владеете этим вопросом, разъясните правильно ли я поступаю?

4 Текущий баланс вычисляется так (сумма пополнений) - (сумма покупок) + (сумма продаж)
Для пользователя с `id`=1 (1+10+100+100) - (1+10+10+100) + (2+2+20+300) = 211 - 121 + 324 = **414**

```
SELECT (IFNULL(SUM(r.sum),0) - IFNULL(SUM(b.sum),0) + IFNULL(SUM(s.sum),0)) `sum`
FROM tbl_user `u`
LEFT JOIN tbl_billing_refill `r` ON u.id=r.uid
LEFT JOIN tbl_billing `b` ON u.id=b.buid
LEFT JOIN tbl_billing `s` ON u.id=s.suid
WHERE u.id=1 GROUP BY u.id;
```

Только вот проблема в том, что запрос вместо ожидаемых **414** выдаёт `6624` = 414*16, то есть одни и те же данные дублируются 16 раз.

Обычно, в подобных ситуациях, когда у меня `COUNT`(`id`), я ставил `DISTINCT` во все `COUNT` и всё работало как нужно.
Я понимал, что я маскирую причину не устранив следствие, но причины я не понимал и устранить не мог.
Вот теперь тот случай, когда в `SUM`(`sum`) `DISTINCT` уже не поставить, так как он будет резать нужные дубликаты, которые я специально включил в тестовые данные.

Помогите правильно и оптимально составить запрос и покажите как устранять эту причину, которую я всегда маскировал `DISTINCT`-ом, чтобы я больше так не делал. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно посчитать суммы по отдельности в подзапросах, и потом уже считать баланс.

```
SELECT rsum - bsum + ssum `sum`
FROM tbl_user `u`,
    (
    SELECT COALESCE(SUM(r.sum),0) rsum
    FROM tbl_billing_refill `r`
    WHERE r.uid=1
    ) q1,
    (
    SELECT COALESCE(SUM(b.sum),0) bsum
    FROM tbl_billing `b`
    WHERE b.buid=1
    ) q2,
    (
    SELECT COALESCE(SUM(s.sum),0) ssum
    FROM tbl_billing `s`
    WHERE s.suid=1
    ) q3
WHERE u.id=1
```

Впрочем, таблица tbl_user тут нафиг не нужна...

По просьбе alexoander вариант для нескольких юзеров:

```
SELECT u.id, q1.rsum - q2.bsum + q3.ssum `sum`
FROM tbl_user `u`,
    (
    SELECT r.uid id, COALESCE(SUM(r.sum),0) rsum
    FROM tbl_billing_refill `r`
    GROUP BY r.uid
    ) q1,
    (
    SELECT b.buid id, COALESCE(SUM(b.sum),0) bsum
    FROM tbl_billing `b`
    GROUP BY b.buid
    ) q2,
    (
    SELECT s.suid id, COALESCE(SUM(s.sum),0) ssum
    FROM tbl_billing `s`
    GROUP BY s.suid
    ) q3
WHERE u.id=q1.id
  AND u.id=q2.id
  AND u.id=q3.id
-- AND u.id IN (1,3,5,128)
```

Если нужно отбирать по небольшому количеству юзеров, имеет смысл добавить соотв. WHERE в подзапросы.

Comment: А одним запросом никак?

Comment: А это ОДИН запрос.

Comment: Это ещё хуже.
Подзапросы же не кешируются?

Comment: Наверно все таки стоит поправить запрос для общего случая, чтобы везде не проставлять uid =1. Чтобы было понятней

Comment: @Ilya Indigo Зачем кэшировать скалярное значение? А если нужно архибыстро - делайте предрасчёты сумм по юзерам, и просто берите готовые значения.

Comment: @alexoander Ок, счас забахаем... готово.

Comment: @Akina Затем, что пользователя постоянно нужно информировать о его текущем балансе, но пополняет баланс, покупает и продаёт он ой как не часто.
Я думал про предподсчёты, но для них всё равно нужно составить запрос.
Посчитать по отдельности, что бы каждый фрагмент попал в кэш, мне больше нравится, но хочется одним запросом, который сразу попадёт в кеш, если, конечно, это возможно.

Comment: @Ilya Indigo А в чём проблема составить запрос для предрасчёта? тем более что он будет проводиться нечасто? не говоря уж о том, что подзапросы у меня - это и есть готовые запросы для предрасчёта.

Comment: @IlyaIndigo если будете использовать кэширование (в случае если пользователю не критично видеть изменения сразу) - то особой разницы, сложный запрос или простой, нет. Главное чтобы считал значения правильно.

Comment: @Akina В любом случае спасибо Вам за решение, Вашу суть я понял, но по крайней мере пока, ответ принять не могу, так как хочу одним кешируемым запросом или подробного разъяснения, почему так как я хочу неосуществимо.

Comment: @IlyaIndigo _хочу ... подробного разъяснения, почему так как я хочу неосуществимо_ Почему невозможно использование SUM(DISTINCT)? да потому что сами суммы неуникальны. Можно было бы выполнить DISTINCT комбинации (sum, sum_id), но SUM() не умеет из группы полей выделить одно поле для суммирования. И вариант с SUM(FUNCTION(DISTINCT value)) - тоже невозможен.

Comment: @Regent Про конкретный случай я с Вами согласен. Но, как писал выше в вопросе, тут общая проблема которая меня мучает много лет, мог ли я избежать DISTINCT-ов в COUNT-ах и что для этого нужно было сделать.

Comment: @Akina Ну так откуда и почему вообще появляются дубликаты, если условия прописаны так, что их быть не должно. Или JOIN в принципе не рассчитан на объединение более 2-ух таблиц?

Comment: @IlyaIndigo Если у Вас 2 начисления и 3 платежа, то после JOIN Вы будете иметь 6 уникальных пар (одно начисление - один платёж).

Comment: @Akina мне казалось так только CROSS работает, а INNER и OUTER должны вести себя иначе. :-(

Comment: @Akina И лишние пары точно кроме DISTINCT-а ничем отсеять нельзя, ни группировкой, не условием, ни ещё чем нибудь?

Comment: Как? каждая пара - уникальна. Ну только разве что случайно совпадёт, ну там два разных платежа по 100 рублей каждый - да вот только их-то как раз объединять и нельзя...

Comment: @Akina сам бы хотел знать как. :-(
Теперь придётся пересмотреть глобально политику применения JOIN-ов.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50767/discussion-between-ilya-indigo-and-akina).